# html changing horizontal align of elements depending on the DIRECTION setting

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a site that is due to support all languages, including RTL (Hebrew, Arabic, Persian, etc.). The applications is developed using AngularJS, Bootstrap and JavaScript.

By setting `dir="auto"` I get the text properly displayed (LTR for ENGLISH, RTL for ARABIC). My problem is with the alignment of elements.

Suppose you need to display a list. When the language is, say, English, the list would look:

```
- Entry 1; this is with a short tail,
- Entry 2; no tail,
- Entry 3; this is with a tail that is longer than the one of the 1st entry
```

If this list would be in, say, Arabic, it would look as follows:

```
دخول 1؛ هذا هو الحال مع ذيل قصير -
دخول 2؛ بلا ذيل، -
دخول 3؛ هذا هو الحال مع ذيل أطول من واحد من دخول 1ST -
```

which obviously should be right align like:

```
                         دخول 1؛ هذا هو الحال مع ذيل قصير -
                                           دخول 2؛ بلا ذيل، -
    دخول 3؛ هذا هو الحال مع ذيل أطول من واحد من دخول 1ST -
```

(my apologies to all Arab speakers, but I'm not one of you and used Google Translate, so I don't know what the quality of the translation is).

So, is there a way I could test the character set of the contents and set `horizontal-align:left` or `horizontal-align:right`?

Hope my question is clear...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. There is an indication on the language of the data being received. I then set the `div` as:

```
<div .... style="text-align:{{User_This_Align}}">
...
```

Within the controller, is set the variable `$scope.User_This_Align` equal to 'left' or 'right' depending on the language of the data.

(This relies on Angular's data binding feature).

Thanks to those that sent their comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. All you have to do is put as follows into a css file:

text-align: right;    --------------    To align it to the right

text-align: left;     --------------    To align it to the left

text-align: center;   --------------    To align it in the center

Comment: Well, the options of `text-align` are not strange to me. My point is how to dynamically change it (from `left` to `right` and vise-versa) depending on the contents of the data to be deployed within the list.

Comment: you could use php and make a variable that changes depending on what language it is. Then you could have an if statement that checks what the variable is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found a solution as shown below.

Answer (score 0):

First try giving direction in class. (Refer CSS direction Property in W3 school) Then depending on the language selected change the direction using ng-class.

Comment: The question is: I get text from the DB, and I don't know if it is English, Arab, Chinese or whatever. I need to find out which language is and then set the alignment to the right or left for the list. This is the challenge.

Comment: Do u get the text when the user select particular language option?

Comment: If the user select Arab or Chinese will you be passing some code or Id to DB to get relevant language data.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. See the solution I found above.